# Double to String keeping trailing zero

Tags: c#

I've tried converting the double value into a string and using the `Replace()` method 
 to replace the ',' to '.'.

This works well but only when the trailing digits are not zero, I need zeros in my string, even if the value is 1234.0. This worked well for the decimal values. I have tried to convert the double to decimal but I lose the decimal digits if there are zeros.

I know I'm missing something. I would be grateful for some suggestions.

Comment: what language is this written in?

Comment: This needs clarification. What is the output you're trying to get from what input? What's not working? What programming language?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This would depend on the language. An example in C#

```
d.ToString("0.00");
```

Would produce a double with 2 decimal places nomatter the values (zero or otherwise).

Answer (score 0):

If this is in Java, check out the [NumberFormat class](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html)'s `setMinimumFractionDigits()` method.

Example:

```
double d1 = 2.5;
double d2 = 5.0;

NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);

String d1s = nf.format(d1);
String d2s = nf.format(d2);

System.out.println("d1s: " + d1s + " and d2s: " + d2s);
```

produces

> d1s: 2.50 and d2s: 5.00

Answer (score 0):

...and in Fortran, you could do something like: :-)

```
      write(*,110) x
  110 format (F5.3)
```

(guess we really have to know what language is being used...)

Comment: +1: I was going to delete my answer -- now that the OP said C# -- but after reading your answer I think I'll leave it.